# Convert the number to decimal

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the below code i have a textbox if i enter a number (ie)10 it should convert to 10.00.Pls help me to do this.

JS:

```
function sample()
    {
    var num ;
    var result = num.toFixed(2); 
    }
```

asp.net:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" value="" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: As specified in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323159/specifying-decimal-places-on-a-variable-in-a-string:

> <%= FormatNumber(num, 2) %>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is proper for ASP, but here's how I would do it in just javascript.

```
var input = document.getElementById("txt");
input.addEventListener("[event desired (click, blur, etc)]", function() {
    var result = parseInt(input.value,10).toFixed(2);
}, false);
```

Since the input is a type string, you need to convert it to a number. The event listener I'm not 100% sure you need, since this is ASP and it's got the `runat:server` but yeah. Convert to integer, fix 2 decimal spots, and there you go.